# редактирование готового шаблона pdf PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Имеется готовый шаблон PDF. Нужно подставлять значения в нужные места по типу ФИО, дата рождение, адрес и тд. средствами PHP. Возможно ли отредактировать уже готовый PDF шаблон не генерируя его заного

Comment: На этот вопрос вам сможет ответить оф документация. http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdf.php.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, но к сожалению времени не много, разбираться в документации времени нет. Я надеялся что кто-то с этим сталкивался раньше и у него будет хотя бы готовый маленький пример